# Assert in GraphDSL

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-stream

I´m using graphDSL of akka stream to create a DSL for my test framework, but now that I´m looking how works I dont think it fit well.

My concern is that it seems like when I make an assert(false) in one of the flows instead of propagate the error in the test it´s getting stuck

I dont know if I´m doing something wrong

My DSL implementation looks like:

```
def given(message: String, musVersion: MUSVersion = ONE) = Source.single(new message(message, musVersion))


 def When(sentence: String) = Flow[message].map(message => {
    try {
      HttpClient.request(message._1, message._2)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        HttpResponse[String](e.getMessage, 500, Map())
      }
    }
  })

 def Then(sentence: String) = Sink.foreach[HttpResponse[String]](response => {
    assert(false)
    thenAction(sentence, response)
    println(s"######## $x")
  })
```

Like I said my test it get stuck instead mark the test as failure because of the assert.

Here my Test code:

```
class TestDSL extends MainDSL {

  private def generateKey(): String = s"""${UUID.randomUUID().toString}"""

  implicit val config = this.getRequestConfig("cassandra")

  val message: String = Messages.message(path = "cassandra", key = "Cassandra " + generateKey())

  info("This test has as requirement create and find an Entity using cassandra connector")
  feature("First DSL") {

    scenario(s"This is a prove of concept of the DSL") {

      RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>

        given(message) ~> When("I make a request") ~> Then("The return code='200'") ~> AndThen("The payload is not empty")
        ClosedShape

      }).run()
    }

  }

}
```

Any idea what´s wrong?.

Regards.

Comment: `assert` throws an AssertionException, which causes processing stage to crash and kicks in [stream supervision strategy](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/stream/stream-error.html#error-handling). Depending on which strategy you're using and how you're materializing the stream in the test you might observe different results - from freezes to test errors. Could you please include your actual test code?

Comment: @J0HN Thanks for the response. I´ve read about the supervisor, but as the documentation says, by default it stop the actor and return the failure. But it´s not what is happening